# How to get an element in an array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I got a simple select element with static options. I want to get an element on a certain index of an array when i click on one option.
Forgive me if this is ridiculous but I am new with Angular JS

Here are the class and the dropdown-list

```js
 $scope.products=[
            {
                "Id":1,
                "Name":"ice cream",
                "Price":8.50
            },
            {
                "Id":2,
                "Name":"salad",
                "Price":8.99
            },
            {
                "Id":3,
                "Name":"fish & chips",
                "Price":10.91
            }
        ]
```

```html
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.selectedOption">
            <option ng-repeat="product in products" ng-model="selectedOption" value="{{product.Id}}">{{product.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

For example when I click on ice cream, next to the dropdown-list, there should be the price of the item.

Comment: there is no `ng-model` on `<option>` . Only the `<select>` itself gets bound to data model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ngOptions` on your `select` - put an `ngModel` on the `select` - and then simply display!

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-options="product as product.Name for product in products">
</select>

<span>Price: {{data.selectedOption.Price}}</span>
```